# How to save log to .txt

Tags: javascript, html

How to save log to .txt ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Stopwatch</title>
<script language="javascript">

var base = 60;

var clocktimer,dateObj,dh,dm,ds,ms;
var readout='';
var h=1;
var m=1;
var tm=1;
var s=0;
var ts=0;
var ms=0;
var show=true;
var init=0;
var filePath = "/Users/ResetOfDirectoryPath/testWrite.txt";

function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

function uncheckedRadio() {

var radio_1 = document.clockform.gName;
var radio_2 = document.clockform.aName;       

if(radio_1.length == undefined)
    radio_1.checked = false;
else
    for(var i = 0; i < radio_1.length; i++)
        radio_1[i].checked = false;

if(radio_2.length == undefined)
    radio_2.checked = false;
else
    for(var i = 0; i < radio_2.length; i++)
        radio_2[i].checked = false;
}

unction clearALL() {
    clearTimeout(clocktimer);
    h=1;m=1;tm=1;s=0;ts=0;ms=0;
    init=0;show=true;
    readout='00:00:00.00';
    document.clockform.clock.value=readout;
    document.clockform.m0.value = '';
    uncheckedRadio();
    nrGola = 1;
}

var nrGola = 1; 
function addMEM() {
if (init>0)
{
    var mC = document.clockform.m0;
    var gol = getCheckedValue(document.clockform.gName);
    var asy = getCheckedValue(document.clockform.aName);

    if(gol != '')
    {
        var mesOut = nrGola + " G: " + gol;

        if(asy != '')
        {
            if(asy == gol)
            {
                alert('Error, asysta taki sam jak strzelca');
                uncheckedRadio();
                return false;
            }

            mesOut = mesOut + ", A: " + asy;
        }
        else
            mesOut = mesOut + ", A: brak";

        mesOut = mesOut + ", " + readout;

        if(mC.value != '')
            mC.value = mC.value + "\n" + mesOut;
        else
            mC.value = mesOut;
       nrGola++;     
       uncheckedRadio();              
    }
    else
        alert('Nie wybrano strzelcy');
}
}


function startTIME() {

var cdateObj = new Date();
var t = (cdateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTime())-(s*1000);

if (t>999) { s++; }

if (s>=(m*base)) {
    ts=0;
    m++;
    } else {
    ts=parseInt((ms/100)+s);
    if(ts>=base) { ts=ts-((m-1)*base); }
    }

if (m>(h*base)) {
    tm=1;
    h++;
    } else {
    tm=parseInt((ms/100)+m);
    if(tm>=base) { tm=tm-((h-1)*base); }
    }

ms = Math.round(t/10);
if (ms>99) {ms=0;}
if (ms==0) {ms='00';}
if (ms>0&&ms<=9) { ms = '0'+ms; }

if (ts>0) { ds = ts; if (ts<10) { ds = '0'+ts; }} else { ds = '00'; }
dm=tm-1;
if (dm>0) { if (dm<10) { dm = '0'+dm; }} else { dm = '00'; }
dh=h-1;
if (dh>0) { if (dh<10) { dh = '0'+dh; }} else { dh = '00'; }

readout = dh + ':' + dm + ':' + ds + '.' + ms;
if (show==true) { document.clockform.clock.value = readout; }

clocktimer = setTimeout("startTIME()",1);
}

function findTIME() {
if (init==0) {
    dateObj = new Date();
    startTIME();
    init=1;
    } 

}

/*
var times = {};
window.onload=function() {
var inpt = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0,n=inpt.length;i<n;i++) {
if (inpt[i].type=="radio") inpt[i].onclick=function() {
    times[this.id]=this.form.m0.value=this.form.clock.value;

} 
}
}
*/

function showTimes() {

var temp = document.clockform.m0.value;

if(temp != '')
{   
    uriContent = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(temp);
    newWindow=window.open(uriContent, 'txt');
}
}



</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=tan>
<form name="clockform">
<table bgcolor=cornsilk align=center cellpadding=5 border=1 bordercolor=burlywood><tr><td>
<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 align=center>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=wheat><input name=clock value="00:00:00.00" style="text-align:center; width:174px; height:35px; font-size:24; font-weight:bold"></td>
<td valign=top bgcolor=wheat><input name=clearer type=button value="Reset" onclick="clearALL()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 bgcolor=wheat>
<input name=starter type=button value="Start" style="width:97px; font-weight:bold" onclick="findTIME()">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input name=marker type=button id ="dupa" value="Mark" style="width:84px" onclick="addMEM()"><br><font style="font-size:9pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>

<tr><td>
<input type="radio" name="gName" value="1" /> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="gName" value="2" /> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="gName" value="3" /> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="gName" value="4" /> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="gName" value="5" /> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="gName" value="6" /> 6<br>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="aName" value="1" /> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="aName" value="2" /> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="aName" value="3" /> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="aName" value="4" /> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="aName" value="5" /> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="aName" value="6" /> 6<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<textarea name="m0"  style="text-align:left; width:83px cols="40" rows="5" readonly="readonly">
</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="showTimes()" value="show times">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How you should write a question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I dont think its a bad question.

Comment: He is faily new to the community and should not be welcomed by downvotes. Think of all the people coming from google to stackoverflow and wondering what the hell is wrong here and now do I have to read the "how to do something else" when I just wanna ask one question.

Comment: The question doesn't even state whether the goal is to write a file on the local file system of the browser versus on the server. It is thus unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript, running in a browser, under normal security conditions, cannot access the user's file system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ajax or something else that can write to the server with the right permissions to write to a log file on the server. The JavaScript itself can not write a log file to the server or the client as it is executed off the server and it does not have access to the clients computer (Image getting viruses through JavaScript if this was true)....Unless you give explicit write access which is very unsafe and very complicated to do.